# Encapsulating Action<T> and Func<T>?

Tags: c#, parameters, action, overloading, func

I'm trying to make a design for some sort of IExecutable interface. I will not get into details, but the point is that I have several Actions that need to be executed from a base class. They may take different parameters (no big deal), and they may/may not return a value.

So far, this is my design:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    // ... snip ...
}

public abstract class ActionWithResultBase<T>: ActionBase
{
    public abstract T Execute();
}

public abstract class ActionWithoutResultBase: ActionBase
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

So far, each of my concrete actions need to be a child from either ActionWithResultBase or ActionWithoutResult base, but I really don't like that. **If I could move the definition of Execute to ActionBase, considering that the concrete class may or may not return a value, I will have achieved my goal.**

Someone told me this could be done with using Func and Action, for which I totally agree, but I can't find a way to have that into one single class so that the caller would know if the action is going to return a value or not.

Brief: I want to do something like:

```
// Action1.Execute() returns something.
var a = new Action1();
var result = a.Execute();

// Action2.Execute() returns nothing.
var b = new Action2();
b.Execute();
```

Comment: As a clarification: my goal is to have an abstract Execute in ActionBase and avoid creating ActionWithResultBase and ActionWithoutResultBase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a lightweight solution, then the easiest option would be to write two concrete classes. One will contain a property of type `Action` and the other a property of type `Func<T>`:

```
public class ActionWithResult<T> : ActionBase { 
  public Func<T> Action { get; set; } 
}

public class ActionWithoutResult : ActionBase {
  public Action Action { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can construct the two types like this:

```
var a1 = new ActionWithResult<int> { 
  CanExecute = true,
  Action = () => { 
    Console.WriteLine("hello!");
    return 10; 
  }
}
```

If you don't want to make `Action` property read/write, then you could pass the action delegate as an argument to the constructor and make the property readonly.

The fact that C# needs two different delegates to represent functions and actions is quite annoying. One workaround that people use is to define a type `Unit` that represents "no return value" and use it instead of `void`. Then your type would be just `Func<T>` and you could use `Func<Unit>` instead of `Action`. The `Unit` type could look like this:

```
public class Unit {
  public static Unit Value { get { return null; } }
}
```

To create a `Func<Unit>` value, you'll write:

```
Func<Unit> f = () => { /* ... */ return Unit.Value; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I waited long before marking your answer, but I really wanted to see if someone came up with a solution. Even when your approach does not quite solve the problem, it is indeed a good answer, and shows a good and nice workaround on how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following interfaces should do the trick -- it's essentially copying the Nullable pattern

```
public interface IActionBase
{
       bool HasResult { get; }
       void Execute() { }
       object Result { get; }
}

public interface IActionBase<T> : IActionBase
{
       new T Result { get; }
}

public sealed class ActionWithReturnValue<T> : IActionBase<T>
{
       public ActionWithReturnValue(Func<T> action) {  _action = action; }
       private Func<T> _action;

       public bool HasResult { get; private set; }
       object IActionBase.Result { get { return this.Result; } }
       public T Result { get; private set; }
       public void Execute()
       {
            HasResult = false;
            Result = default(T);
            try 
            { 
                 Result = _action();
                 HasResult = true;
             }
            catch
            {
                HasResult = false;
                Result = default(T);   
            }  
       }

}

public sealed class ActionWithoutReturnValue : IActionBase
{
      public bool HasResult { get { return false; } }
      object IActionBase.Result { get { return null; } }
      public void Execute() { //... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can ignore the return value of a method right? You don't *have* to use it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct on that, but I don't think that would be something design-wise to have. Also, someone suggested me to return always bool for those no-returns that would just indicate that the operation was successful, but I also think that's not correct. If the operation should not return a value, why force it?

Comment: @Alpha - I agree with you that if an operation doesn't naturally return something it shouldn't. Returning "true" isn't right because egnerally you shouldn't return "false" you should throw an exception. However I still don't understand your design goal - your objective seems to be based on syntactic sugar and I don't see what you're accomplishing that you couldn't just get Action and Func to solve. I think you need to explain what's the problem with them?

Answer (score 0):

what about something simple:

```
public class ActionExecuter
{
    private MulticastDelegate del;
    public ActionExecuter(MulticastDelegate del)
    {
        this.del = del;
    }

    public object Execute(params object[] p)
    {
        return del.DynamicInvoke(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also thought about something similar, but my problem is that I won't know at compile time which type is returned. I could always make ActionExecuter<T> and make Execute return T, but that beats situations were I need not to return anything.