# Combining Action and Func in one parameter

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, action, func

I have many methods that require some logging with the same pattern. Some methods need to return some value, some don't. I have created a method with Action parameter to avoid copypasting all of the logic. It looks like this:

```
private void Execute(Action action)
{
   Logger.Start();
   try
   {
      action();
   }
   catch(Exception exception)
   {
      Logger.WriteException();
      throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       Logger.Finish();
   }
}
```

Now I have some calls that like that

```
public void DoSomething(string parameter)
{
    Execute(() => GetProvider(parameter).DoSomething());
}
```

But I need some function that return values. What are the best ways to do it?
I have found two now:

1) Create a copy of Execute method with Func

```
private T Execute<T>(Func<T> action)
{
   Logger.Start();
   try
   {
      return action();
   }
   catch(Exception exception)
   {
      Logger.WriteException();
      throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       Logger.Finish();
   }
}
```

This method works but has some copy paste as well.

2) Trick the parameter into being an Action:

```
public Result DoSomething(string parameter)
{
    Result result = null;
    Execute(() => result = GetProvider(parameter).DoSomething());
    return result;
}
```

This does not require copy paste but does not look so nice.

Is there a way to join Action and Func somehow to avoid any of these methods or may be there is another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I use the second of your approaches. I couldn't find a nice way to do it any other way, so I'll be interested to see any answers to your question!

Comment: It seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4279210/55209

Comment: consider using aspects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you put this pattern (Logger.Start, try/catch/finally, Logger.WriteException, Logger.Finish) into your `Logger` class itself? At that point, the amount of code duplication is fairly minimal in general, enough that wrapping the `Func<T>` as an `Action` with closure semantics isn't really necessary. I suspect you'd want your logging to has as minimal a processing overhead as possible. (or, who cares? Premature optimization!) But I would definitely consider throwing the `Execute` overloads into `Logger` itself. EDIT: I guess `Logger` isn't threadsafe, but that isn't a concern, eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A third option is to still overload `Execute`, but make the `Action` version work in terms of the `Func` version:

```
private void Execute(Action action)
{
    // We just ignore the return value here
    Execute(() => { 
        action();
        return 0; 
    });
}
```

Of course all this would be simpler if `void` were more like a "real" type (like `Unit` in F# et al), at which point we could just have `Task<T>` instead of `Task` and `Task<T>` as well...

Comment: I thought of this method as well but did not even include it as it looks quite dirty to me as you are pretending to be a Func by using int for a generic type and returning default value that is never used.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: I think that's cleaner than assigning to a local variable within an `Action` to make it act like a `Func<T>`, personally. But the point is that it's within `Execute`, not within `DoSomething` - you only need this "dirt" in a single place, not in multiple callers.

Comment: @ JonSkeet May be you are right and it's less dirty. Or may be the same dirty but in one place :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a copy of `Execute` that converts the `Func` into an `Action`. You only have to write that ugly code once, and you don't end up with a complete second copy of the `Execute` method:

```
private T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    T result = default(T);
    this.Execute(() => { result = func(); });
    return result;
}

...

public Result DoSomething(string parameter)
{
    return Execute(() => GetProvider(parameter).DoSomething());
}
```

Comment: @ p.s.w.g The problem with this approach is that I have both value types and classes as return. And your code won't compile because local variable is not initialized before return.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Just initialize `result` to `default(T)`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g Right, didn't think about default one. Actually this update is pretty logical for my second method, don't know why I have not though about it.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g By the way return should be before Execute it seems in your example (DoSomething function)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik oops you're right. Yes `default(T)` is a very handy little trick.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g By the way, for some reason compiler thinks that this is a recursive call so I had to cast the ()=>result=func() to Action. It does not return a value, so I don't know how it thinks it's func...

Comment: May be Jon Skeet is right and it's better to pretend that you are Func<T> and not use the return value than to pretend that you are Action and use additional variable.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The assignment operator returns the value assigned, so `i = 5` is five, not `void`.  In your case, `result = func()`, when evaluated as an expression, resolves to whatever `func()` resolves to, not `void`, which is why the lambda has a return value.

Comment: @Servy how's that? (see my updated answer). Seems slightly nicer than casting to an `Action`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sure, fixing it isn't much of an issue either way, I was just explaining the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option. Instead of having the logging framework call your actual code, have your actual code call the logging framework. Something like this would do the trick (greatly simplified).

```
public class LoggerScope : IDisposable {

    private bool disposed;

    public LoggerScope() {
        Logger.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if(!disposed) {
            Logger.Finish();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
        using(var scope = new LoggerScope()) {
            // actual code goes here
        }
```

Handle exceptions separately by catching and logging them only once at the top level of your code.

Advantages:

- Avoids the need for lambdas all over the place, so the exception stack trace is a bit cleaner.
- You can add arbitrary contextual data to the `LoggerScope` class, e.g. GUID, timestamp, logical task description text.

Comment: The disadvantage is that you have to create a special class for each special case. Though I have used this approach for doing reader writer lock.